# webdriver cannot find the show more link with jscontroller

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I"m trying to click the show more in the play store.

```html
<div class="PFAhAf" jscontroller="XO1Ihd" jsaction="JIbuQc:bRsdTc(i3y3Ic);">
   <div role="button" class="U26fgb O0WRkf oG5Srb C0oVfc n9lfJ M9Bg4d j7nIZb" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;j9grLe:.CLIENT;HUObcd:.CLIENT" jsshadow="" jsname="i3y3Ic" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
      <div class="Vwe4Vb MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd" style="top: 14px; left: 25.2344px; width: 98px; height: 98px;"></div>
      <div class="ZFr60d CeoRYc"></div>
      <span jsslot="" class="CwaK9"><span class="RveJvd snByac">Show More</span></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried below codes and none of them works.

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("SHOW MORE").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Show More").click()
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('U26fgb O0WRkf oG5Srb C0oVfc n9lfJ M9Bg4d j7nIZb').click()")
driver.find_element_by_class_name(
                "U26fgb O0WRkf oG5Srb C0oVfc n9lfJ M9Bg4d j7nIZb").click()
```

any clue?

Comment: share your website link.

Comment: you can select any app which has a lots reviews e.g. amazon. Then, you scroll down the reviews until you see the Show More link /button
https://play.google.com/store

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("SHOW MORE").click()
```

need change to

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Show More").click()
```

Comment: i've tried already and not working.

Comment: share your website link